# Unable to import the requirements in XML format in Testlink 1.9.14

Tags: php, xml, testlink

Under Requirement Specification of a project,I tried to import a simple XML file with list of requirements and once I click the Upload File button.I am getting "Warning: Please choose the file to upload".

Any help or suggestions is highly appreciated.

Please find the below image for error.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not the same problem, I also had problems to import requirements, test cases and custom fields previously exported in xml format. In my case there was no answer, testlink simply refused the import without showing the reason on the web browser or in the logs under /var/testlink/logs.

In the end, **the cause was that an important dependency was missing: php-xml. I installed it and the problem was fixed.**

Answer (score 0):

I also have this symptom in testlink 1.9.20.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2iQg.png)

Comment: Please do not post answers that only mention "I have this problem too".

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33259159)